# How can I check the encoding of the tag in Mp3 file?

Tags: character-encoding

I want to ensure that the tag inside is using unicode, otherwise it may display incorrectly in media player.

For example, many mp3 in my pc is japanese so they are having janpanese character tag. If they are using japanese encoding there might be problem. How can I ensure that it is using unicode?

I use Mp3Tag tool to edit the tag, does it convert the text to unicode automatically?

Comment: a quick search on the forums... and I found a discussion about the problem and how to remedy it. http://forums.mp3tag.de/index.php?showtopic=11925

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is just to open up the file in a hex editor and have a look see.  You can find the detail about where the bytes are supposed to be in the file [in this document](http://id3.org/d3v2.3.0).  There are plenty of good and free hex editors on the internet, check out HxD if you don't have one already.